# Get error with struct member field being a function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to have struct member being a regular function pointer (not a class member function pointer).  Not sure why the compile error.  I am running g++ 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.  Thanks.

```
$ g++ te5.cc
te5.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
te5.cc:18:9: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
  t.func = dum;
         ^
te5.cc:19:6: error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope
  (t.*func)();
```

Code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef void pfpv(void *obj);
typedef struct {
    pfpv  func;
    void *obj;
} strTimer;

void dum(void* p) {
    printf("in dum()\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    strTimer t;
    t.func = dum;
    (t.*func)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C++, so why not pleasing code like `std::function`?

Comment: The `typedef struct` looks very c-ish as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved by making `pfpv` a function pointer instead of a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef void (*pfpv)(void *obj);

typedef struct {
    pfpv  func;
    void *obj;
} strTimer;

void dum(void* p) {
    printf("in dum()\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    strTimer t;
    t.func = dum;
    t.func(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that in C++ you should not use raw function pointers, but prefer `std::function<>` instances instead because the function pointer does not cover all object types that can act as a callable function in C++. (I.e. function pointer can be wrapped in a `std::function<>` instance but not all things that can act like callable functions can be expressed as function pointers.)

Answer (score 2):

There are several mistakes here.

1. `typedef void (*pfpv)(void *obj);` … you'd left out the first `*`, so `pfpv` was just a function type, not a function *pointer* type.
2. `(t.func)();` You'd used pointer-to-member-function call syntax, but your `t.func` is just a normal function pointer, so use `.` not `.*`.
3. Furthermore, you're not passing any arguments to a function that expects a `void*`. We can pass `nullptr`, for now.

[Here it is compiling, with those fixes in place](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2138464c9858af26).

This whole debacle could have been avoided if you'd used the far simpler `std::function`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct strTimer
{
    std::function<void(void*)> func;
    void* obj;
};

void dum(void* p)
{
    std::cout << "in dum()\n";
}

int main()
{
    strTimer t;
    t.func = &dum;
    (t.func)(nullptr);
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5585ffc49dc694f)

No need for that antiquated C cruft!

Presumably, passing `void*` as argument is also designed to satisfy some primordial C idiom, perhaps by passing in `&t` (instead of `nullptr`) to simulate member functions. You should consider using lambda functions and other modern language features; your program will be much easier to write, maintain and debug.

Comment: Thanks @lightness-races-in-orbit, I will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your function pointer typedef (it doesn't specify a function pointer). Change it like so:

```
typedef void (*pfpv)(void *obj);
```

Also the call of the function pointer is wrong:

```
(t.func)(&t);
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d0c0a61585ba509)

Comment: @packetie I know, because I tested it :-)

Comment: Thanks again πάντα ῥεῖ!